The debug feature in Visual Studio Code displays "file cannot be accessed"
Sorry to trouble you with this beginner programming issue.
I am creating some html code in Visual Studio Code, and I am able to run it when I use the "open with live server" option. However, when I try to run the code "normally" by using the debug feature (also usable by pressing F5) I am unable to run the code.
I would really like to know the issue and how to solve it, and also to be able to actually use the debug feature.
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<title>テンプレート</title>
<link href="../../_common/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=M+PLUS+1p:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../_common/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="container">
<h1>タイトル</h1>
<h2>サブタイトル</h2>
</div><!-- /.container -->
</header>
<main>
<div class="container">
<section>

</section>
</div><!-- /.container -->
</main>
<footer>
<div class="container">
<p>JavaScript Samples</p>
</div><!-- /.container -->
</footer>
</body>
</html>

I tried googling the issue and I tried work-around solutions such as using the "open with live server" option, but I was ultimately unable to understand what causes the issue.
